# Hide/Show menu item depending on account works but

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a management menu item available if a user has a Manager account. If the user does not, the menu item is hidden. It works fine but something is off on the css.

If i click an item within the management menu and then click another menu item outside of the management, it doesnt work and the hyperlink shows # at the end. Why? Also when i shrink the menu, it shows the label of the menu item. If i take the div out, it works fine but of course the management menu will be avialable to every account. Please see screenshot below.

```
<div id="management_menu" style="display:none">
 <li class="mm-dropdown">
  <a href="#"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-chain"></i><span class="mm-text">Management</span><span class="badge badge-primary"></span></a>
      <ul>
                 <li class="mm-dropdown">
                    <a href="#"><span class="mm-text">Accounts</span></a>
                          <ul>
                             <li>
                                <a tabindex="-1" href="user_profile_view_all.php"><span class="mm-text">All Accounts</span></a>
                             </li>
                             <li>
                                <a tabindex="-1" href="user_profile_view_dispatchers.php"><span class="mm-text">Dispatchers</span></a>
                             </li>
                             <li>
                                <a tabindex="-1" href="user_profile_view_parts_department.php"><span class="mm-text">Parts Department</span></a>
                             </li>
                             <li>
                                <a tabindex="-1" href="user_profile_view_technicians.php"><span class="mm-text">Technicians</span></a>
                             </li>
                             <li>
                                <a tabindex="-1" href="user_profile_view_specialists.php"><span class="mm-text">Specialists</span></a>
                             </li>
                             <li>
                                <a tabindex="-1" href="user_profile_view_supervisors.php"><span class="mm-text">Supervisors</span></a>
                             </li>
                             <li>
                                <a tabindex="-1" href="user_profile_view_managers.php"><span class="mm-text">Managers</span></a>
                             </li>
                          </ul>
                 </li>
                 <li class="mm-dropdown">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="management_invoices_view.php"><span class="mm-text">View All Invoices</span><span class="label label-warning"></span></a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="mm-dropdown">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="management_leads_view.php"><span class="mm-text">View All Leads</span><span class="label label-warning"></span></a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="mm-dropdown">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="management_parts_view.php"><span class="mm-text">View All Parts</span><span class="label label-warning"></span></a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="mm-dropdown">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="management_techinspections_view.php"><span class="mm-text">View All Tech Inspections</span><span class="label label-warning"></span></a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="mm-dropdown">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="management_techinspections_view.php"><span class="mm-text">View All Contract Inspections</span><span class="label label-warning"></span></a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="mm-dropdown">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="management_checklists_view.php"><span class="mm-text">View All Checklists</span><span class="label label-warning"></span></a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="mm-dropdown">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="management_hdds_view.php"><span class="mm-text">View All HDDs</span><span class="label label-warning"></span></a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="mm-dropdown">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="management_partswarranty_view.php"><span class="mm-text">View All Parts Warranty</span><span class="label label-warning"></span></a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="mm-dropdown">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="management_mkregchecklist_view.php"><span class="mm-text">View All MK Reg. Checklists</span><span class="label label-warning"></span></a>
                 </li>
      </ul>
```

```
<script>
var logged_in = "<?php echo $_SESSION['account_type'] ; ?>";
   if(logged_in === "Manager") {             
        document.getElementById('management_menu').style.display = 'block';

   } else {
       document.getElementById('management_menu').style.display = 'none';                          
   }
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is you have `<li class="mm-dropdown">` without a parent `<ul>`. Or at least you have a `<div>` above it that which wouldn't be strictly valid html as you can only embed `<li>` directly within a `<ul>`.

I suggest it would be better to remove the management_menu div and change to `<li class="mm-dropdown" id="management_menu" style="display:none">`.

The `#` comes about largely from `<a href="#">`. If your CSS has padding for the `<li>` then unless you click exactly on the inner text the `<a href="#">` will be triggered.

On a second note, hiding the management menu with CSS is easy to circumvent. It would be less prone to malicious activity by generating the management menu in PHP only when the condition is met.  Otherwise anyone with a curious mind is able to un-hide the management menu within their browser.